# Is there a way to contact specific user?

Tags: support

Below one of my questions, I started comment chat with one of the Worldbuilding users.

The chat itself is totally interesting for me and for the user, but I am afraid that it might be off-topic for the rest of the people.

Is there some means of continuing such discussion somewhere else than in comments or chat?

I am afraid of using chat because I know that I am from Europe, while the user may be from USA, which means about 7-8 hours time difference by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to contact specific user?

Generally speaking, no. Stack Exchange is not a social network, and does not aim to be. Hence, unless a user discloses contact information, there is no easy way to contact a specific user either inside or outside of the SE network.

> Is there some means of continuing such discussion somewhere else than in comments or chat?
>
> I am afraid of using chat because I know that I am from Europe, while the user may be from USA, which means about 7-8 hours time difference by default.

Chat is asynchronous. You can leave a message in chat, and the other user comes by later, reads it and responds. In that regard, chat works in exactly the same way as comments.

Assuming that you feel the conversation is useful, but not necessarily *where it is currently located*, I would recommend just **creating a chat room and moving the conversation there.** Just because it's chat doesn't mean it has to involve everyone being present at the same time. Create a chat room, copy all previous comments into it, and leave a link at the end to it like "let's continue this over here: [link to chat room]". Flag the post for moderator attention and request a comments cleanup. All done.

Answer (score 5):

You know that you can anytime create a chat room apart from the main worldbuilding chat (or any other main chat rooms, for that matter), where you and any interested user may contribute. For example, we made a [room specificially dedicated to the WB blog](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27736/universe-factory).

That way you do not disturb other people, and can share without problem. If it is unused for 14 days it will get frozen. And eventually might be deleted. But for the purpose of that discussion, the chat will be available.

If you want it fully private, then I believe you have to take it out of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Wow, I did not know it. Thanks!

Comment: For reference of those who may read this:  Note the minimum requirement to participate in chat — though the OP satisfies the criterion, engaging in comments on a user's own question could happen with those who do not.