# Is there a way to message a user?

Tags: support

I was looking at Worldbuilding just now and noticed a [question that had been closed](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/229453/eyewitnesses-to-subterranean-beings-i-can-t-be-the-only-one) because it was asked "in character" - unfortunately it was also locked because of some unfortunate comments made to that person, which I'm not able to read.  Anyway, how can I message the original poster ( @john21851 ) to tell him about [Homo floresiensis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_floresiensis) and a [professor emeritus](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-10752687/British-anthropologist-believes-theres-evidence-Homo-species-alive.html) who holds out hope for meeting an *ebu gogo*?  (No, I don't think this is probable, but let's keep sci-fi interesting!  Besides, I admire anybody 4-foot high who can take on a *Megalania* with a spear... it's hard to give up hope for their survival.)

I see there's [another question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2735/is-there-a-way-to-contact-specific-user) about this, but I don't see how to *invite* this person to a chat room if the question isn't linked to it.

Comment: [The question about 3-4 ft tall people which has been locked out](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/229453/eyewitnesses-to-subterranean-beings-i-can-t-be-the-only-one).

Comment: I don't know the comments that caused the question to be locked, but my bet is that some people either didn't take them seriously, or that they crushed their viewpoint rather than offering think-food to their mind to help them evolve/broaden/sharpen said viewpoint. Both are nasty, and doesn't help anyone out there : Not the asker, not the commenters, and not people like you who can give such mental candies :).

Comment: Currently the question does seem open for comments...

Answer (score 7):

There is no way for a user to message another user out of the blue like that.

If you are in the same chat room, you can tag them there. You can also comment on their question to call their attention, or tag them in a post (specially if they participated in it).

Stack Exchange is not really a social network, so it is really lacking in things like messaging. This is by design. If messaging was a feature, there would be pressure to use SE resources to maintain and evolve that in lieu of other features more related to the Q&A format of the network.

If someone wants to be reached outside SE, they can always leave links to their social networks in their profiles.

On a personal note, I am glad that SE is like this. I would not like to be contacted by someone to have a pedantic discussion about the technicalities of creatures that look like women distributing swords in ponds nor mages accidentally sodomizing themselves due to misusage of a magical word, among other themes I have dabbled on in this site.

Answer (score 2):

##### You Shall Not Pass

There's only one *sure* way to get around the quandry at this point in time. It looks like this particular querent joined on 3 May 2022, and is thus very new. If whatever happened a couple days ago doesn't send him fleeing in terror from the horror show that is WB.SE, chances are good he'll come up with another question --- you could simply write a comment on that other query and invite him to discuss the closed query in chat.

The only other potentially viable ways are to vote to reopen the closed question; edit the question such that it is likely to be reopened (I'm not suggesting this, but you could try to sneak a direct message to the querent in your edit (like "hey! I can help! write a comment on my own XYZ question!")); and lastly petitioning L. Dutch to unlock the present query so you can simply write a helpful comment or start a discussion with the [querent](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/95992/john21851).